# OpenVPN UDP connections timing out

Tags: routing, openvpn, timeout, gateway, udp

So I have a virtual server set up on amazon, which I will call OSERV, to run openvpn on 3 different ports. All of the OpenVPN servers are acting as routing gateways. 2 of the servers that are running over TCP work great, but my UDP server, while it is able to make local connections, always times out for external IPs. I will call it UDPSERV.

So when I ssh through UDPSERV to OSERV, it works fine. But when I try to ssh (or do any other type of activity) anywhere else through UDPSERV, the connection times out. I will call the external server i am testing on as EXSERV. I have been watched the log at verbosity level 6, and I see the packets being sent and received when trying to make the connection to EXSERV. So I know that works. I have also ran wireshark on the client machine, and see it sending and receiving packets just fine also when SSHing to EXSERV.

```
ssh root@ESERV -o ConnectTimeout=60
Connection reset by ESERV port 22
```

Though oddly, when I watch the log when doing activity through UDPSERV to OSERV, it doesn't seem to show it.

I have confirmed the MTU is not a problem. Interestingly enough, I can actually push >4000 bytes through as the MTU. I did attempt setting it to 500 at one point.

So I think that's everything I can say for the setup of this question. If anyone can help me figure out why this isn't working, I'd really appreciate it. Below this are all of my configurations.

[Edit] Oh yeah. I did a netcat through UDPSERV from my client to EXSERV and it worked fine.

All 3 of the openvpn server configs have the following relevant settings:

```
dev tun
ifconfig-pool-persist ipp.txt
push "redirect-gateway def1 bypass-dhcp"
keepalive 10 120
comp-lzo
persist-key
persist-tun
```

**Different settings:**
**Serv1**:

```
port 80
proto tcp
server 10.8.0.0 255.255.255.0
```

**Serv2**:

```
port 443
proto tcp
server 10.8.1.0 255.255.255.0
```

**UDPSERV**:

```
port 123
proto udp
server 10.8.2.0 255.255.255.0
```

The amazon security settings have the following allowances:
**Incoming ACCEPT**: TCP22, TCP80, TCP443, UDP123
**Outgoing ACCEPT**: Everything

**The following is my iptables setup:**

```
#Clear everything out
iptables -P INPUT ACCEPT
iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT
iptables -P OUTPUT ACCEPT
iptables -F
iptables -X
iptables -t nat -F
iptables -t nat -X
iptables -t mangle -F
iptables -t mangle -X
iptables -t raw -F
iptables -t raw -X

#All connections
iptables -I FORWARD -m conntrack --ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT

#Serv1
iptables -I FORWARD -i tun0 -o eth0 -s 10.8.0.0/24 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o eth0 -s 10.8.0.0/24 -j MASQUERADE

#Serv2
iptables -I FORWARD -i tun1 -o eth0 -s 10.8.1.0/24 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o eth0 -s 10.8.1.0/24 -j MASQUERADE

#UDPSERV
iptables -I FORWARD -i tun2 -o eth0 -s 10.8.2.0/24 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o eth0 -s 10.8.2.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
```

**I have also tried the following settings for UDPSERV:**

```
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -m state --state NEW -p udp --dport 123 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD -i tun2 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I FORWARD -i tun2 -o eth0  -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o eth0 -s 10.8.2.0/24 -j MASQUERADE
```

The following is the openvpn log at verbosity level 6. The client connected from 45.16.1.12 . I then connected to the OSERV's ssh. I then attempted to connect to EXSERV SSH which timed out after 30-ish seconds. [OpenVPN log](http://s000.tinyupload.com/download.php?file_id=86716102765076467225&t=8671610276507646722576785) . Please let me know if you have trouble downloading the file and I'll try a different service.

Comment: can you post openvpn log from `UDPSERV`?

Comment: The following is the openvpn log at verbosity level 6. The client connected from 45.16.1.12 . I then connected to the OSERV's ssh. I then attempted to connect to EXSERV SSH which timed out after 30-ish seconds. [OpenVPN log](http://s000.tinyupload.com/download.php?file_id=86716102765076467225&t=8671610276507646722576785)  Please let me know if you have trouble downloading the file and I'll try a different service.

Comment: I guess there is some routing problem. try google for `MULTI: bad source address from client`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So it turns out the problem is that I was running on udp port 123 (the ntpd port). I guess some router out there must have special coding for that port to only allow small packets, or something. Time to find a different common udp port to run on.